Idenity Verification endpoint in Plaid not working
I am having issues with the endpoint API Plaid call '/identity_verification/create', where when I run it in the Anonymous Window I get this error:
System.CalloutException: Unexpected HTTP Response: 404:Not Found { "display_message": null, "error_code": "INVALID_FIELD", "error_message": "Please provide a customer reference.", "error_type": "INVALID_REQUEST", "request_id": "TAeIYdoK1a32BKE", "suggested_action": null } 
This my block code for this request:
`public class PlaidIdentityRequest {
    public String client_id { get; set; }
    public String secret    { get; set; }
    public Boolean is_shareable { get; set; }
    public Boolean gave_consent { get; set; }
    public String template_id { get; set;}
    public String shareable_url { get; set; }
    public PlaidIdentityAddress address { get; set; }
    public PlaidIdNumber id_number { get; set; }
    public PlaidUser user { get; set; }    
}

public class PlaidIdentityAddress {
    public String country { get; set;}
}

public class PlaidIdNumber {
    public String value { get; set;}
    public String type { get; set;}
}

public class PlaidUser {
    public String given_name { get; set; }
    public String family_name {get; set;}
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }
}

//Method to create a Plaid user request
 public static PlaidIdentityRequest PlaidUserRequest(String firstName, String lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth, String ssn, PlaidIdNumber idNumber) {
    PlaidUser user = new PlaidUser();
    user.given_name = firstName;
    user.family_name = lastName;
    user.dob = dateOfBirth;
    PlaidIdentityAddress userAddress = new PlaidIdentityAddress();
    userAddress.country = 'US';
    PlaidIdNumber userId = new PlaidIdNumber();
    userId.value = ssn;
    userId.type = 'us_ssn';
    PlaidIdentityRequest request = new PlaidIdentityRequest();
    request.client_id = clientId;
    request.secret = plaidSecret;
    request.template_id = 'idvtmp_daNh9TmaSZbhkL';
    request.gave_consent = true;
    request.is_shareable = true;
    request.user = user;
    request.id_number = idNumber;
    String body = JSON.serialize(request);
    String url = '/identity_verification/create';
    String shareableUrl = request.shareable_url;
    
    HttpResponse res = callout(url, body);
    
    if(res.getStatusCode() != 200) {
        String format = 'Unexpected HTTP Response: {0}:{1}\n\n{2}';
        String[] parts = new String[]
        {
            String.valueOf(res.getStatusCode()),
            res.getStatus(),
            res.getBody(),
            request.shareable_url = res.getBody()                
        };
        String message = String.format(format, parts);
        throw new CalloutException(message);
    }
    
    return
        (Plaid.PlaidIdentityRequest) JSON.deserialize
        (res.getBody(), Plaid.PlaidUserRequest.class);
        
}`

Thank you in advance if somebody has any input!
I have already change client_id for client_user_id but I get a message also that the required field client_id is missing, so I do not know what other place to go.
